# SwiftUI add Animation

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is a simplified representation of my code. How do I add an animation to `Text("hi")` here? It's a really simple appearance animation.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    @State var showText:Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        List{
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "square")
                Text("tap")
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                showText.toggle()
            }
            if (showText) {
                Text("Hi")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test()
    }
}
```

[image: appear]
[image: disappear]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `withAnimation` block:

```
.onTapGesture {
    withAnimation {
        showText.toggle()
    }
}
```

You can also change the default animation type, duration etc:

```
withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.4)) { ... }
```

Comment: Solved very well!!